# Restrict Publishing Site Access on Public Facing SharePoint Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, publishing-site

I am new to SharePoint 2013 (Office365) and want to create a publishing site that is internet facing that anyone can see but parts of it require a login.

I am not sure how to go about this ideally I do not want to use the public site if possible.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well that's what it would be.. a Public site with Login access? As soon it's on the Internet, it's Public.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mackieeE, I guess what I am really asking is can a publishing site be an internet facing site without login because at the moment our public site is like any other ordinary site you type in the address and you see it as is, but when you go to the  publishing site address it requires a login to office 365.

Answer (score 3):

In a way, your public facing O365 website is already configured that way. If you're not signed in you get this view:

[image]

You have a sign-in option, but can't create posts to the Blog directly. But you can access blog posts when they are published.

When you're signed-in you have more control of the site:

[image]

You can take the entire site Offline at the top left - and you can create blog posts if you have permissions.

I guess you should start experimenting with two different browsers to accomplish what you're really after.

Comment: @user40575 You're welcome. I hope it helps.